# yum update errors with glibc dependency resolution

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I try and update my 2014.03 Amazon ec2 instance using simply "sudo yum update" I get the following error output.  Any suggestions on fixing this would be swell.

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00     
2141 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.43.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.12-1.107.43.amzn1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-36.81.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.4.73-64.112.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.35-43.137.amzn1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
           Requires: glibc-headers = 2.12-1.107.43.amzn1
           Removing: glibc-headers-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
               glibc-headers = 2.12-1.107.43.amzn1
           Updated By: glibc-headers-2.17-36.81.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               glibc-headers = 2.17-36.81.amzn1
           Available: glibc-headers-2.17-36.80.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               glibc-headers = 2.17-36.80.amzn1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 13 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
audit-2.2-2.17.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of audit-libs = ('0', '2.2', '2.17.amzn1')
audit-2.3.2-3.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-2.2-2.17.amzn1.x86_64
aws-amitools-ec2-1.5.1-0.0.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with aws-amitools-ec2-1.4.0.9-2.0.amzn1.noarch
aws-amitools-ec2-1.5.2-0.0.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with aws-amitools-ec2-1.5.1-0.0.amzn1.noarch
glibc-2.17-36.81.amzn1.i686 has installed conflicts audit < ('0', '2.3.0', None): audit-2.2-2.17.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-2.17-36.81.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts audit < ('0', '2.3.0', None): audit-2.2-2.17.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc = ('0', '2.12', '1.107.43.amzn1')
glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.45.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.45.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc = ('0', '2.12', '1.132.45.amzn1')
glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.45.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc-headers = ('0', '2.12', '1.132.45.amzn1')
glibc-devel-2.17-36.81.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.45.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.17-36.81.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc-headers = ('0', '2.17', '36.81.amzn1')
glibc-headers-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc = ('0', '2.12', '1.107.43.amzn1')
```

Comment: Perhaps this would have been better asked over on ServerFault.  If so my apologies as I didn't realize that site existed until a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

1， `yum install yum-utils.noarch`

2， `package-cleanup --cleandupes`

then it will tell you something like this

---

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
————————————————————————————————————————————
in case

---

glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc = ('0', '2.12', '1.149.el6')

---

3， `yum check dependencies`

yum check dependencies
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc = ('0', '2.12', '1.149.el6')
Error: check ['dependencies']

4， `rpm -e --nodeps glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64`

5， `yum clean all`

6，  `yum update -y`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved by:

```
sudo package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

and then run the update again:

```
sudo yum update
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but to avoid other's responding to a question I can no longer test, we ended up moving off of that server and discarding it.  I never did get a chance to verify if Nick Z.'s answer would fix things.  I believe we tried what greentor suggested but it didn't seem to clear the issue.  Thanks to all for trying to answer.